# MVC pattern, one or many controllers/servlets?

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller

I am working on a Java EE application and I am trying to implement it following the MVC pattern. I don't use any frameworks (e.g Spring) in order to implement the MVC structure. I just write my own Models, Views and Controller/s.

I started implementing my application using different Servlets for every functionality (ex. LoginServlet, RegisterServlet) but I noticed that many people say that one Controller (Servlet) is enough to handle all the application's functionalities. However, I don't understand how could that happen without getting a messy code as a result. The way I am thinking it is having one Servlet/Controller with multiple if/else statements in order to check where the request comes from. The result would be a huge doPost or doGet method with a lot of if/else statements which sounds like a bad idea.

To summarize, is it a good or bad idea to have a different servlet for every functionality of the application, and if it's bad how could I achieve the same thing by using one servlet and without creating huge methods?

Comment: Why you want to re-invent the wheel? Any good reason for not-using any framework?

Comment: @ Sundararaj Because maybe he wants to learn how to do the things right ? If he depends always on a framework to do hist stuff he will never really learn properly.

Comment: @Alexander, this can be a good reason

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the Pattern you are using. My suggestion is to start reading design patterns.  One example of how you can have a single controller is the "Front Controller" pattern. The famous "Struts" is an example using it:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller

Here is a link with example implementation:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/frontcontroller-135648.html

Answer (score 0):

No, you should divide your servets in a logical way. Actually you should divide your packaging in big logical divisions. For the servlets for example AuthenticationServet to handle all authentication flow,  RegistrationServlet, EShopServlet etc

Packages

```
com.myapp.servlets.*
com.myapp.models.jpa*
com.myapp.models.(something)*
com.myapp.services.*
```

Comment: Question is about no.of servlets, not packages.

Comment: @SundararajGovindasamy You should read my answer again before down voting. My answer is telling him how to name and organize the servlets and I am also *SUGGESTING* to do the same with the packages.

Comment: I commented on your answer, but downvoting? it's NOT me.

Answer (score -1):

Good and bad are subjective.

There's usually one `DispatcherServlet` (aka Front Controller servlet) that will accept HTTP requests and route the code to an appropriate handler given the URL.

I think REST and micro-services go one step further and expose functionality as multiple HTTP endpoints.

This is another case of Java EE, or your interpretation of it, being behind the times.

I would do this with Spring using multiple REST endpoints.

Comment: He doesnt use any framework and having one blowed up servlet will do him any help

Comment: I understand that.  I pointed out examples of how it's been done before by others.  You can do REST and microservices without a framework.  If you voted this down, I'd like to see you revert it or post something besides a comment so we can see what level of expertise you plan to bring to the party.  "Blowed up servlet"?  Please explain.

Comment: @duffymo is correct for the micro services part although I am not sure that he was serious or joking when he mentioned the REST by hand :) But yes, REST can be hand coded as well as long as you follow the basic RESTful principles.

Comment: REST is a style.  Of course you can do it on your own.